# Why is Grunt Uglify keeping my function names?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a grunt configuration for grunt-contrib-uglify as so:

```
options: {
    mangle: {
        topLevel: true
    },
    compressor: {
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        conditionals: true,
        booleans: true,
        unused: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        drop_console: true
    },
    dist: {
       cwd: 'public',
       expand: true,
       src: ['**/*.js'],
       dest: 'public'
    }
}
```

Here is some sample code as to what I have:

```
(function (Core, $, undefined) {
   Core.Dom = {
      AddItem: function() {
         ... code ...
      }
   };

   ... etc ...

}(window.Core = window.Core || {}, jQuery));
```

After I run my grunt task the compression works in terms of getting rid of white space and such, but the code still has the functions label with it's names. For example, in the compressed file `Core.Dom.AddItem` would be `a.Dom.AddItem`. Is there a way to mangle the names to where it would be `a.b.c` where `b=Dom` and `c=AddItem`? I have tried `mangle: true` as well, but it keeps the names of the functions. Anyone have any clue as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: This is actually an open issue on grunt-contrib-uglify - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/216 - treat this like a bug that isn't fixed (for anyone else that is having the same problem).

Answer (score 3):

Just imagine having this in **another file**:

```
window.Core.Dom.AddItem()
```

If uglify renamed `Core.Dom` in `a.b`, that other file would fail, because `window.Core.Dom` is now `window.Core.b`.

Uglify renames what it's safe to rename.

The reason it renames `Core` to `a` is that, in this context, it can safely rename all occurrences of `Core` inside the function without without having to worry about its use outside the function.

Also, see the concept of closures.

Comment: It's a bug, this doesn't answer the question - not least as UglifyJS itself has the option...

Comment: It's not a bug, it's what's expected from a minifier.

Comment: It is a bug - as the minifier in question explicitly has the option "toplevel" for it - https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options - the option was added in 2013. Gah - edit - your answer is "why" - but the mangle-props option was added in June this year - there is a bug relating to mangle, but mangling the properties has been possibly via script for years beforehand.

Comment: I didn't know about --mangle-props, but, as they say, "this will probably break your code" (for the reason I explained). So not a good idea I'd say.

Comment: Exactly - but if it's not exporting names then it's also a better way to obfuscate the code which is the reason most people use it (space saving isn't an issue if gzip is used on the server)